# A way to pass build-time arguments from .env file to Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Is there a way to pass .env-file variable from docker-compose up (or docker-compose build) invocation into the Dockerfile execution environment without really weird hacks?

I need to pass USER NAME variable that will be used in build-time environment to become this user.

I've tried to do this today and spent over 6 hours with different approaches and not a single one allows me to use the pre-made .env file user variable. It works for me only when I hardcode user name into Dockerfile, sadly.

I've spend so much time on stackoverflow today reading all the answers and tailoring my environment, but I still can't reach what I'm trying to do. I know there are many similar questions. But they don't seem to help whatsoever...

Help would be much appreciated! Thanks...

P.S. Example .env:

```
version: '3'
services:
  terra-validator:
    image: terra-validator
    env_file:
      - terra-validator/variables.env
    environment:
      - NEWUSER=${NEWUSER}
    build:
      context: terra-validator
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NEWUSER=$NEWUSER
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG NEWUSER
ENV NEWUSER $NEWUSER
RUN adduser $NEWUSER
USER $NEWUSER
CMD whoami
```

Adduser and useradd commands does not work... They always prints out same 3-4 type of errors depending on my approaches...

Comment: #1 If your Dockerfile needs a .env file, Why not create it close to your Dockerfile and use COPY or ADD ? #2 Do you need to send a  simple string at the  docker build moment to be used in your Dockerfile?. For example, receive a string and create a folder with this string as name?

Comment: Your Docker image shouldn't have a dependency on any specific host user; you shouldn't have to rebuild your image if a different user runs it.  Can you use a fixed user name in the Dockerfile?  If there's a problem you encounter doing this, can you edit the example to have more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by the followinf approach:

**Docker compose file**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  terra-validator:
    image: terra-validator
    environment:
      - NEWUSER=${NEWUSER}
    build:
      context: terra-validator
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NEWUSER=${NEWUSER}
```

**PS:** I removed the `env` file.

**Bash script file**

```sh
NEWUSER=$1 # For example coming from command line
NEWUSER=${NEWUSER} docker-compose up
```

Let me know if it works for you too.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you, that worked very well for me.

Comment: Well! Please upvote it too, if you want. :)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give your full error, so here just give you a workable solution, FYI:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  terra-validator:
    image: terra-validator
    build:
      context: terra-validator
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NEWUSER=$NEWUSER
```

**.env:**

```
NEWUSER=tester
```

**terra-validator/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG NEWUSER
ENV NEWUSER $NEWUSER
RUN adduser $NEWUSER --disabled-password --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone"
USER $NEWUSER
CMD whoami
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "20210811_default" with the default driver
Building terra-validator
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 065cf14a189c
Step 2/6 : ARG NEWUSER
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6c11feb31ac0
Step 3/6 : ENV NEWUSER $NEWUSER
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 365472fb8bf2
Step 4/6 : RUN adduser $NEWUSER --disabled-password --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone"
 ---> Running in 3156249774f8
Adding user `tester' ...
Adding new group `tester' (1000) ...
Adding new user `tester' (1000) with group `tester' ...
Creating home directory `/home/tester' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Removing intermediate container 3156249774f8
 ---> 8debf4402db6
Step 5/6 : USER $NEWUSER
 ---> Running in 5f86175c5d7b
Removing intermediate container 5f86175c5d7b
 ---> 400f7951c4be
Step 6/6 : CMD whoami
 ---> Running in 5fe9cf8cc6f8
Removing intermediate container 5fe9cf8cc6f8
 ---> f63f2e284104
Successfully built f63f2e284104
Successfully tagged terra-validator:latest
WARNING: Image for service terra-validator was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating 20210811_terra-validator_1 ... done
Attaching to 20210811_terra-validator_1
terra-validator_1  | tester
20210811_terra-validator_1 exited with code 0
```

**Explanation:**

The value defined in `.env` will be used by `args` in `docker-compose.yaml`, then be passed to `Dockerfile ARG`. During user setup, you'd better add `--disabled-password --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone"` to remove some error message. Finally, in the `docker-compose up` log, you could see `whoami` prints `tester`.